# MX-Record: IP or FQDN?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I have not found any reference to this in the RFCs and hope to find a reliable answer here.

Domain `mail.example.com` runs a mail server. I want to set the MX record for the domain `awesomeexample.com` pointing to `mail.example.com`. Can I use the FQDN or do I have to use the static IP address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK The `MX` record data format is formalised in [`RFC 1035`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#section-3.3.9) which defines that MX records should point to host names (FQDN's) rather than IP-addresses.

> ```
> MX RDATA format
>
>     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
>     |                  PREFERENCE                   |
>     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
>     /                   EXCHANGE                    /
>     /                                               /
>     +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> ```
>
> where:
>
> **PREFERENCE**
> A 16 bit integer which specifies the preference given to
> this RR among others at the same owner.  Lower values
> are preferred.
>
> **EXCHANGE**
> A **`<domain-name>`** which specifies a host willing to act as
> a mail exchange for the owner name.
>
> MX records cause type A additional section processing for the host
> specified by EXCHANGE.  The use of MX RRs is explained in detail in
> [RFC-974].

(of course IPv6 wasn't conceived then yet, but an IPv6 host will (also) do a lookup for an AAAA record instead.)